# how to add the binaries and other files to rootfs in yocto using .bb recipes

Tags: yocto, build-system

```
DESCRIPTION = "Copies hello-binaries to the image"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI += "file://hello "
S = "${WORKDIR}"
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0777 hello ${D}${bindir}
    }
#FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-dev = "ldflags"
```

*In the above recipe i commented the line FILES_* then also the hello binary is adding to the image how is it possible? I have no idea how the recipe is copying binaries to image.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILES_${PN}` has a default value that includes among other things "${bindir}/*". So appending to the value in the recipe isn't needed.

You can see the default value in meta/conf/bitbake.conf and check what the value ends up as with `bitbake -e <hellorecipe> | grep ^FILES_`